# Order of element in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have started taking a course on group theory and I have some confusion on few things

If $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a normal subgroup, and $P$ is a prime number then

Suppose $y\,H \in G/H$ is the generator of a group of order $P$.

I have learned that a group of order $P$ is cyclic. However, I am confused to why does this make the following true

$$
y^{P}H=(y\,H)^{P}=H
$$

Why is $(y\,H)^{P}=H$ and $y^{P}H=(y\,H)^{P}$?

Finally, assuming that $y^{P}H=(y\,H)^{P}=H$ is true why would this imply that $y^{P} \in H$?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean a group with prime order is cyclic.

Comment: $(yH)^P = H$ because the order of the group is $P$; any element $y$ will then have order dividing $P$, meaning that its order will be 1 or $P$. That is, $y^P = 1$ for all $y\in G/H$

Comment: You need to go back and read up on the definition of order of an element in a group, what the identity element of a quotient group is and what it means for two cosets to be equal. Things will automatically get clearer to you.

Comment: It's best to state the assumptions. "If $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a normal subgroup, and $P$ is a prime number then.." You've skipped over a lot of assumptions. It is always important in math to be aware of the conditions of the problem and to communicate them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we probably need more context, as in exactly what the book you're reading says. However, I'll give this a go anyways.

I think it's most likely that your book says $y^P H=(yH)^P$. This follows because of the way we define the operation in quotient groups; we have $xHyH=xyH$ for all $x,y\in G$, so $x^2H=(xH)^2$ and you can extend to any integer $n$ by induction.

Now you need to see that if $xH=H$ then $x\in H$. This is true because

$$xH=\{xh\mid h\in H\}$$

in particular, we always have $x\in xH$ because $x=x\cdot 1\in xH$ because $1\in H$ (because it is a subgroup).

Now, if $xH=H$, then because $x\in xH$, we must have $x\in H$. So in particular if $y^PH=H$, then $y^P\in H$.

also, I forgot to add that $(yH)^P=H$ because $P$ is the order of the group $G/H$. If this statement does not make sense to you then you really need to go back and reread earlier definitions.